# Font size changing upon page focus or field focus

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, focus

This is only in Chrome I've noticed, not Firefox.  I have noticed something about 2 weeks ago on a site I designed **and also a very large client's site**.  I believe I've seen it elsewhere.  when I initially load the page and before doing anything else (click, tab, shift-tab), the username and password are one size.

When I click or tab or otherwise focus on the page, the font size gets larger for both the username and password fields (but the field size itself doesn't change).

[image]
[image]

I looked for some type of `::focus` or `::active` pseudo class but there is none.  And both fields resize the font on page click or tab.  Does anyone know why this is, and is it correctible (in Chrome) in any way?

Comment: without actually looking at the code it's tough to figure it out. Since we can't actually log into the site, what is the public facing site so we can look?

Comment: Its part of chrome and happens on any form that has auto-filled fields. Looks like the shadow root element gets a `pseudo="-internal-input-suggested"` which is styled with the small text and on focus it changes to `pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder"` which has the normal styles. Not sure how to force styles for the `-internal-input-suggested`. Just trying to add some more info for anyone that might know how to force the styles.

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS you are using to the question.

Comment: Any luck here? I am running across the same problem. Only on autofilled fields.

Comment: At this point I think I'm fighting an uphill battle to change this.  The 2+ upvoted comment above might provide a starting point but depending on the order of process might be difficult to override or even catch/debug.

Comment: Facing the same issue with Chrome. It seems no solution has been found yet.

Comment: Same problem in Opera...

Answer (score 3):

The following does the trick:

```
input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. No difference with or without this style addition.

Comment: Also does not work for me. The autofilled font changes when I click anywhere on the page, next to the input, for example. From the element inspector, I can see that, only then, does the -webkit-autofill css rule get applied. But it's useless, since the font also displays correctly post-click, without the -webkit-autofill rule. I need a css rule that gets applied before any clicks.

Comment: Also, the correct font family is already correctly applied to the input element, upon page load, as per the element inspector. Any kind of autofill rule to set the same font family, would be superfluous. It's just that Chrome simply refuses to use the specified font family, unless you click somewhere first. Not sure why it has to work that way.